# Regular expression to exactly match the last path segment of an URL without parameters, except if the path ends with a trailing slash

Tags: regex, url, path

The goal of my regular expression adventure is to create a matcher for a mechanism that could add a trailing slash to URLs, even in the presence of parameters denoted by `#` or `?` at the end of the URL.

For any of the following URLs, I'm looking for a match for `segment` as follows:

1. `https://example.com/what-not/segment` matches `segment`
2. `https://example.com/what-not/segment?a=b` matches `segment`
3. `https://example.com/what-not/segment#a` matches `segment`

In case there is a match for `segment,` I'm going to replace it with `segment/`.

For any of the following URLs, there should be no match:

1. `https://example.com/what-not/segment/` no match
2. `https://example.com/what-not/segment/?a=b` no match
3. `https://example.com/what-not/segment/#a` no match

because here, there is already a trailing slash.

I've tried:

1. This primitive regex and their variants: `.*\/([^?#\/]+)`. However, with this approach, I could not make it not match when there is already a trailing slash.
2. I experimented with negative lookaheads as follows: `([^\/\#\?]+)(?!(.*[\#\?].*))$`. In this case, I could not get rid of any `?` or `#` parts properly.

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Try `(.*\/[^?#\/]+)([?#][^\/]*)?$` and replace with `$1/$2`, see https://regex101.com/r/M6mKAV/2. I added `\n` o the negated character classes since the example text is a multiline string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match urls, you might use

```
\b(https?://\S+/)[^\s?#/]+(?![^\s?#])
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https?://\S+/` Match the protocol, 1+ non whitespace chars and then the last occurrence of `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^\s?#/]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char `?` `#` `/`
- `(?![^\s?#])` Negative lookahead, assert that directly to the right is not a non whitespace char other than `?` or `#`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7VehI2/1).

In the replacement use group 1 followed by `segment/`

---

For a match only instead of a capture group:

```
(?<=\bhttps?://\S+/)[^\s?#/]+(?![^\s?#])
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tpsajj/1).

Answer (score 4):

[Lookahead and lookbehind conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/8355969) are so powerful!

```
(?<=\/)[\w]+(?(?=[\?\#])|$)
```

P.s: I just added `[\w]+` that means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`.
Of course URLs can contain many other character like `-` or `~` but for the examples provided it works nicely.